# Initializing a Generic.List in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constructor

In C#, I can initialize a list using the following syntax.

```
List<int> intList= new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
```

I would like to know how that `{}` syntax works, and if it has a name. There is a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable`, you could call that.

```
List<int> intList= new List<int>(new int[]{ 1, 2, 3 });
```

That seems more "standard". When I deconstruct the default constructor for the List I only see

```
this._items = Array.Empty;
```

I would like to be able to do this.

```
CustomClass abc = new CustomClass() {1, 2, 3};
```

And be able to use the `1, 2, 3` list. How does this work?

**Update**

Jon Skeet answered

> It's calling the parameterless
>   constructor, and then calling Add:

```
> List<int> tmp = new List<int>();
> tmp.Add(1); tmp.Add(2); tmp.Add(3);
> List<int> intList = tmp;
```

I understand what is does. I want to know how. How does that syntax know to call the Add method?

**Update**

I know, how cliche to accept a Jon Skeet answer. But, the example with the strings and ints is awesome. Also a very helpful MSDN page is:

- *[Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)*

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is called a *collection initializer*. It's calling the parameterless constructor, and then calling Add:

```
List<int> tmp = new List<int>();
tmp.Add(1);
tmp.Add(2);
tmp.Add(3);
List<int> intList = tmp;
```

The requirements for the type are:

- It implements `IEnumerable`
- It has overloads of `Add` which are appropriate for the argument types you supply. You can supply multiple arguments in braces, in which case the compiler looks for an `Add` method with multiple parameters.

For example:

```
public class DummyCollection : IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Not a real collection!");
    }

    public void Add(string x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called Add(string)");
    }

    public void Add(int x, int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called Add(int, int)");
    }
}
```

You can then use:

```
DummyCollection foo = new DummyCollection
{
    "Hi",
    "There",
    { 1, 2 }
};
```

(Of course, normally you'd want your collection to implement `IEnumerable` properly...)

Comment: Shame the arguments were the wrong way round - but fixed now :)

Comment: So why does it care that the type is enumerable? it doesn't seem to add anything other than making C# more aware of .NET, similar to IDisposable.. makes me wonder why foreach requires JUST a compat signature, and not interfaces.. I thought the idea was so C# wouldn't be specifically tied to a 'lang'

Comment: @meandmycode: foreach isn't tied to IEnumerable because pre-generics there was no other way of exposing an iterator without boxing. With generics I'm sure it would have *just* relied on IEnumerable<T>. (Continued)

Comment: As for collection initializers requiring IEnumerable, it's a good indication that the type really *is* a collection type, rather than another type which just happens to have an Add method (e.g. DateTime.Add).

Comment: I wish I could use array initializer-like syntax for collections too without having to repeat the type. Like this: `List<int> a = {}`. Or at least something like in Java `List<MyReallyLongTypeName> a = new List<>()`. Instead I get CS0622

Comment: Ah just found out that this is available in C#9 as `List<int> a = new() { ... }`. Awesome!

Answer (score 7):

Read *[Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)*. Basically you could this with every custom type that is a list (implements IEnumerable).

Answer (score 4):

They're called [collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) (also see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx)), and the way they work is by looking for an `Add()` method that can do their bidding.  It calls `Add()` for each of the integers you have in your curly braces.

The search for the `Add()` method is pure compiler magic.  It's hardcoded to find a method of that name.

Comment: Not sure where you've got the word "default" from there - they're just "collection initializers".

Answer (score 2):

The name you're loooking for is "Collection Initializer".  It works under the hood by looking for a method named Add on the collection type and calling it for every value that you specify.

More details: [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a shortcut to the .Add method.  I've never tried to override it, though, so I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: It is possible, try implementing an IDictionary

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, the addition of items via object initialization searches a method Add. So, as List<int> will have void Add(int), it will work.

To use it in your class, just add

```
class CustomClass { 
   public void Add(int num) {
      // Your code here
   }
}
```

Your class should implement IEnumerable, as Hallgrim pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually using the `.Add` method.  Meaning it's calling `.Add` for each item in the brackets inside of the constructor.